# AWS Cognito Hosted URL redirect takes a long time and often times our

Tags: amazon-cognito

When redirecting to AWS Cognito from our application, it always takes a minute plus and often times out.   The same is true for the login screen on Cognito - in the case when we finally get there.

The problem is only in our production environment.  Our dev environment works fine.

What could we be missing?  Is there a way to see what is happing to the request in the network or on Cognito side?

Here is the timeout:
504 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.